# Jboss AS 7.1.1 cannot start

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jboss7.x

I'm trying to start my jboss-as and i receive this error:
Starting jboss-as: -bash: /home/ec2-user/tools/jboss-as/bin/standalone.sh: Permission denied

The /jboss-as/ has permission (775 - jboss-as:jboss-as)

Edited:

```
Starting jboss-as: /etc/init.d/jboss-as: line 81: /var/log/jboss-as/console.log: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of `/var/run/jboss-as': Operation not permitted
grep: /etc/init.d/jboss-as: line 92: /var/log/jboss-as/console.log: Permission denied
/var/log/jboss-as/console.log: No such file or directory
grep: /var/log/jboss-as/console.log: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What does ls -l on bin folder return?

Comment: @britulin http://pastebin.com/sCYhsHB7

Comment: So, you are probably not starting that script as jboss-as user.
Try `su jboss-as`, then run the script again.

Comment: @britulin i edited my post with a more detailed log, please check it. Ps: the directory /var/log/jboss-as/ has permission = 775 - jboss-as:jboss-as

Answer (score 2):

Check the Jboss AS folder (and sub-folders) has got right set of permissions. When Jboss starts it writes stuff to logs and obviously those folders would need permission too. Also check the start command permissions (Obviously if your above steps are correct, then there would be permissions for the start command).

Comment: @WilkerIceri -  If you Jboss directory and subdirectories have got the right permissions for the user then you shouldn't have this problem, as I mentioned in the answer above. Try starting the Jboss as root and see if it starts. If so it's obvious the problem is with the permissions.

Comment: I edited my post with a more detailed log, please check it. Ps: the directory /var/log/jboss-as/ has permission = 775 - jboss-as:jboss-as

Comment: @WilkerIceri - What permission has  '/var/log/jboss-as/console.log' got?

Comment: Permission 775, user and group jboss-as.

Comment: I use the commands: sudo chown -fR jboss-as:jboss-as /var/log/jboss-as/ AND sudo chmod 777 -R /var/log/jboss-as/

Comment: Did yo utry running as root/su to see if it starts at-least? If it runs as root we can at-least nail down that it's a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

generally default jboss installation recommend installation folder under /root. People give full permission to that folder but not '/root'. :)
i got  the same issue. fixed it by moving that folder under jboss user home directory.